# Responsive element positioning

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My apologies I may have just not been using the correct terminology in my searches as I'm sure this has been answered a couple thousand times.

So I know a lot about CSS and HTML but not as much as I'd like. Most of what I know is for fixed (non-responsive) websites. While I do know a bit of responsive like % instead of px I've run into a problem when resizing the width of my browser to simulate the 3 displays (mobile tablet laptop/ desktop).

I have 2 elements side by side. All is well on desktop. Well when I shrink to Tablet and Mobile the element (artist name and social links) overlap the artist image on the left. As well as the menu disappears (would like info on that too if you don't mind (Rebel Mouse Social also disappears in mobile size)).

How would I code so that the artist name and social link elements get moved to underneath the image instead of overlapping?

I'd eventually like to work solely in DreamWeaver and do away with Joomla because after 3 years it's beginning to feel pretty restrictive.

Thank you in advance for reading this I really appreciate you (anyone) taking the time to read all of this.

Working Demo here http://www.blackandyellowrecords.com/mca/jlegacy

**CSS (containted inside Joomla article with HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                                    

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #D6D6D6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}
/* ~~ Element/tag selectors ~~ */
ul, ol, dl { /* Due to variations between browsers, it's best practices to zero padding and margin on lists. For consistency, you can either specify the amounts you want here, or on the list items (LI, DT, DD) they contain. Remember that what you do here will cascade to the .nav list unless you write a more specific selector. */
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p {
    margin-top: 0;   /* removing the top margin gets around an issue where margins can escape from their containing div. The remaining bottom margin will hold it away from any elements that follow. */
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px; /* adding the padding to the sides of the elements within the divs, instead of the divs themselves, gets rid of any box model math. A nested div with side padding can also be used as an alternate method. */
    font-family: Ash;
        color: 000;
}
a img { /* this selector removes the default blue border displayed in some browsers around an image when it is surrounded by a link */
    border: none;
}
/* ~~ Styling for your site's links must remain in this order - including the group of selectors that create the hover effect. ~~ */
a:link {
    color:#414958;
    text-decoration: none; /* unless you style your links to look extremely unique, it's best to provide underlines for quick visual identification */
}
a:visited {
    color: #4E5869;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover, a:active, a:focus { /* this group of selectors will give a keyboard navigator the same hover experience as the person using a mouse. */
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* ~~ this container surrounds all other divs giving them their percentage-based width ~~ */
.artcontainer {
        background-image: url('/images/icons/jlegheaderfade.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right top;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout. It is not needed if you set the .container's width to 100%. */
}
/* ~~ This is the layout information. ~~ 
1) Padding is only placed on the top and/or bottom of the div. The elements within this div have padding on their sides. This saves you from any "box model math". Keep in mind, if you add any side padding or border to the div itself, it will be added to the width you define to create the *total* width. You may also choose to remove the padding on the element in the div and place a second div within it with no width and the padding necessary for your design.
*/
.artcontent {
    padding: 0 0;
}
/* ~~ This grouped selector gives the lists in the .content area space ~~ */
.artcontent ul, .artcontent ol { 
    padding: 0 0px 0px 0px; /* this padding mirrors the right padding in the headings and paragraph rule above. Padding was placed on the bottom for space between other elements on the lists and on the left to create the indention. These may be adjusted as you wish. */
}
/* ~~ miscellaneous float/clear classes ~~ */
.fltrt {  /* this class can be used to float an element right in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: right;
    margin-left: 8px;
}
.fltlft { /* this class can be used to float an element left in your page. The floated element must precede the element it should be next to on the page. */
    float: left;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.clearfloat { /* this class can be placed on a <br /> or empty div as the final element following the last floated div (within the #container) if the overflow:hidden on the .container is removed */
    clear:both;
    height:0;
    font-size: 1px;
    line-height: 0px;
}

.artcontainer #artistpic{
        position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    float: left;
        width: 90%;
        height: auto;
        z-index: 5;
}

.artistname{
    position:absolute;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 400px;
    line-height: .9;
    float: left;
    left: 65%;
    top: 12%;
}
/*SOCIAL FEED*/
.rebel{
    float:none;
    z-index:1;
}
/*SOCIAL ICONS*/
.sicons{
    position:absolute;
    float: left;
    left: 68%;
    top: 14%;
    font-size:10px;
}
/*SOCIAL ICON BLUR*/
.sicons img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}
 /*HOVER BLUR*/
.sicons img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}

.artistmenu{
    float:none;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top: 525px;
    width: 99.9%;
}

-->
</style>

<link href="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="SpryAssets/SpryMenuBar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<div class="artcontainer">
  <div class="artcontent">
    <div class="artistpic">
       <p><img src="/images/artists/jleg.png" alt="Jlegacy" width="459px"/></p>
    </div>
    <div class="artistname">
    <h1><strong>JLegacy</strong></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="sicons"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/jlegacydatruth" target="_blank"><img src="/images/icons/twitter.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/JLegacysFinest" target="_blank"><img src="/images/icons/fb.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
        <a href="http://instagram.com/jlegacysfinest" target="_blank"><img src="/images/icons/insta.png" width="30px" height="30px"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="artistmenu">
    <ul id="MenuBar1" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
          <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Social</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"> Streaming Music</a></li>
          <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Releases</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Albums</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mixtapes</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Singles</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Mailing List</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="rebel">
        <center>
        <script type="text/javascript" class="rebelmouse-embed-script" src="https://www.rebelmouse.com/static/js-build/embed/embed.js?site=JLegacysFinest&height=1500&flexible=0&scrollbar_theme=light-2"></script>
        </center>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
var MenuBar1 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar1", {imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
</script>
    <!-- end .content --></div>
  <!-- end .container --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wowowo, 2 more para and it was a TMH publications worth of material...do **google for media queries** mate......!! :)

Comment: @NoobEditor LOL loved your comment

Comment: Lol Thanks I like writing books HAHA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements you mention is position:absolute, so by changing the top and left values, you can position them under the image

ex.

```
.artistname {
  top: 92%;
  left: 49%;
 }
```

This isn't exactly the point of responsive design but it'll work for you.. Of course you' ll need media query for that.

Comment: WADR mate...`media query` is all he needs....what you suggested would get applied overall for all dimensions otherwise!!! :)

Comment: Naele thanks for your response I'll test that out along with Googling Media Query as NoobEditor said.

Thanks everyone, sorry for the book :-p Just wanted to be specific and not disrespectful about asking.